# Redux: How to pass parent props into the initial state of a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Ok this is bugging me! In react I had a Test component receiving props to create its initial state, like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const {items} = this.props
    this.state = {
        items: {...items},
        score: 0
    }
}
```

The items passed to it (which become part of the state) are items to test - it starts removing those items when they have been tested on until state.items is empty - wherein the test is completed.

Trying to do this in redux, I have the following reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/action-types'
import Store from '../Store'

const initialState = {
    items: {},// I want items to contain the props passed to this component
    score: 0
}

const testWrapperReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
    let newState = null
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.QUESTION_ANSWERED: {
            let {items, score} = state
            delete items[action.english]
            score += action.isCorrect
            newState = {...state, items, score}
            break
        }
        default:
            newState = state
    }

    return newState
}

export default testWrapperReducer
```

How do I set initialState here, using the props given to the test component by its parent? Or is there a better way to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: You should with redux create a golabal store and instead of passing the props to the component you can call and action that updates the redux store and connect the child component to the Store using connect function from redux

Comment: Usually is the other way around, you load your data into the redux store and then using `connect` you send the data to the components as props ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be sendind the items as props from the father, instead i'd send the items from the father to redux and use the connect to receive them in the son.

Code explanation:
- You receive props in the constructor, 
- Send items to redux using an action 
- Receive them as props
- use the props to render the items

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

const Item = (props) => {
    <div>{props.item.name}</div>
}

class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.setItems(this.props.items)
    }
  render() {
    return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items.map((item) => {
                    return <Item item={item}></Item>
                })}
            </div>
        )
  }
}

CreateChat.propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array,
    setItems: PropTypes.func
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setItems: (items) => dispatch(actions.setItems(items))
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(List);
```

Comment: How would I do this if I'm using functional components since I don't have a constructor available there, and I can't use useEffect because I want this to happen before the first render and only happen once?

Comment: @Daksh maybe by using ref? It is trigger before first rendering and is not modified while ref.current=value is not called